# AWSALB, AWSALBCORS cookies and FIrefox

Tags: firefox, cookies, session-cookies, sticky-session, aws-alb

I’m interested in whether the browser version can affect ALB routing (AWSALB, AWSALBCORS cookies) ?

For example, there is an application that is managed by two instances (A and B) and in the case of the browser version of Firefox 74.1 and older, most requests are processed by A, and if use Firefox 75, requests are sent  to instance B.
I looked at the https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/75.0/releasenotes/ list of changes that were made to the latest version of the browser and could not find a change that may affect this.